# Laravel return one record where max value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, max

I'm trying to return one record with a max value as an object. When I do this:

```
public function highestExpense()
    {
        return auth()->user()->expenses()->max('amount');
    }
```

It works, and I get the highest value. But I want to have the whole record returned, so I also have access to the expense name, created_at, and so on.

This didn't work for me:

```
return auth()->user()->expenses()->max('amount')->get();
```

It seems like a simple solution but the answer is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, to get the record that has the highest amount you could just add an `orderBy` and the grab the first row:

```
auth()->user()->expenses()->orderBy('amount', 'desc')->first();
```

This should give the `expense` with the highest amount.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's always the easiest things I cannot think of, horrible. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Hardist Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Collection method `sortByDesc` as follows :

```
return auth()->user()->expenses()->sortByDesc('amount')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally,

This is your try,

```
return auth()->user()->expenses()->max('amount')->get();
```

This will work in Normal case where there is only one maximum value of `amount` column in the table.

So long as there isn't a collision with the `max` column and another column within the table, this might work.

If there are more than one maximum value this will not work.

So, As [Ross Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033654/ross-wilson) said above, You have to order the rows in descending order and get the first row like:

```
auth()->user()->expenses()->orderBy('amount', 'desc')->first();
```

This will work perfectly because even if there are more than one `max`, this will give first row with maximum value of the column `amount`.

Comment: `max('amount')` will return a number. You can't call `get()` on a number